# CSS - nth child/of type or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like a comma to display on all my child elements and 'and' before the last entry and a full stop at the end.

So I would like it to display... You searched for A,B,C,D and E.

At the moment I can only get it to display.... A,B,C,D, and E.

I can am using nth to add commas and full-stops etc but there is one issue I cannot solve, and it is at the second last element it displays both a comma and 'and' I can target the second last element fine as it is colored red in the example below but I can't get it to remove the comma.

There could be between 1 and 9 entries from the form. Can anyone help with this. Is it better to be a JS solution?

```
ul.yousearchedfor li:not(:empty):not(:last-child):after {
  content: ", ";
}
ul.yousearchedfor li:after {
  content: ",";
}
  

ul.yousearchedfor li:nth-last-child(2) {
  content: "";
  color: red;
}
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child:before {
  content: "and ";
}
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child:after {
  content: ".";
}
```

Comment: Instead of `ul.yousearchedfor li:not(:empty):not(:last-child):after` you should use `ul.yousearchedfor li + li:not(:last-child):before {content: ', '}` (add comma before second, third, fourth and not-last element).

Comment: I like the Oxford comma personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to my comment above

The main point is to add commas **before** 2nd and next elements, instead of putting after all but last one.

```css
li {list-style: none; display: inline-block;}

ul.yousearchedfor li + li:not(:last-child):before {
  content: ", ";
}
 

ul.yousearchedfor li:nth-last-child(2) {
  content: "";
  color: red;
}
ul.yousearchedfor li + li:last-child:before {
  content: "\00a0 and ";
}
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child:after {
  content: ".";
}
```

```html
<ul class="yousearchedfor">
  You searched for <li>A</li>
</ul>

<ul class="yousearchedfor">
  You searched for <li>A</li><li>B</li>
</ul>

<ul class="yousearchedfor">
  You searched for <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>
</ul>

<ul class="yousearchedfor">
  You searched for <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li><li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here, it is really appreciated. I don't think I was consice enough, however. There could be just ONE entry. In that instance (as far as I can see) it will display You searched for and A. Anyway round this?

Comment: @user13928344: than it's for a quite easy update. Check the answer now.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel. The last example worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this comma with by using an escaped unicode character such as `/a0`.

As long as your CSS slow is ordered correctly, you shouldn't even need to check for anything like `:not(:last-child)` as the following styles will account for the last child anyway. I also removed the `content` property from your `ul.yousearchedfor li:nth-last-child(2)` selector as the `content` property is only supported by pseudo-elements and is not needed here.

Here is the finished product, both with and without the Oxford comma:

### Without Oxford comma

```css
body, ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
li { list-style: none; display: inline-block; }
ul.yousearchedfor li + li::before { content: ", "; }
ul.yousearchedfor li:nth-last-child(2) { color: red; }
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child::before { content: "\a0 and "; }
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child::after { content: "."; }
```

```html
<ul class="yousearchedfor"><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li><li>E</li></ul>
```

### With Oxford comma

```css
body, ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
li { list-style: none; display: inline-block; }
ul.yousearchedfor li + li::before { content: ", "; }
ul.yousearchedfor li:nth-last-child(2) { color: red; }
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child::before { content: ", and "; }
ul.yousearchedfor li:last-child::after { content: "."; }
```

```html
<ul class="yousearchedfor"><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li><li>E</li></ul>
```